# Github Action not triggered when pushing to branch

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

My `build_and_test.yml` file in `.github/workflows` is as follows:

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - name-of-my-branch
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    # Code to build
```

However, when I push to any branch other than the `main` branch, the build doesn't trigger. Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I realized that this Github Actions file was on the main branch, and Github **uses the actions that are configured for the branch that is getting pushed**. It doesn't do anything if `name-of-my-branch` has different `on: push: branches:` specified in its `.github/workflows/build_and_test.yml`. So `branches: name-of-my-branch` in the `main` branch is a bit deceptive - a build-on-push will only occur if that branch is specified under `push` in its own `.yml`.

I pulled from `main` to `name-of-my-branch` to update the `build_and_test.yml`, pushed, and the build was triggered.

Comment: You ended up helping me too. My `.github/` was inside the `terraform` folder. I just moved to the root folder of the repo and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Based on experience, another possibility  is that the `.github` directory and the `yaml` file in it have not been staged even when doing `git add *`. So no action was triggered when you pushed.

I had to do `git add .github/workflows/myaction.yml` specifically to have it staged.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me -
https://github.com/actions/checkout/discussions/277#discussioncomment-1522374
e.g. - feature/branch_name

My branches names are feature/my_branch